# How to remove modifiers from multiple objects at once

Tags: modifiers

You can add a modifier from one object to multiple other objects using Ctrl+L. Is there a way to delete modifiers all at once?

Comment: You can do the same what you did to add them, just remove modifiers from active object

Comment: Yes remove the modifiers from one, then select all and make the one without modifiers active and CTRL+L > link modifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Mr Zak and Robert Gützkow, you can select the objects you wish to remove all modifiers from, then select an object with no modifiers, hit CTRL+L, and link the modifiers. This will get rid of all of them on all of the objects.

Comment: Yes, thank you!